# react-native firebase remote config

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-remote-config

```
if (__DEV__) {
        firebase.config().enableDeveloperMode();
    }


    firebase
        .config()
        .fetch()
        .then(() => firebase.config().activateFetched())
        .then(() => {
            // Chain additional firebase config methods if needed
            console.log("activated ");
            firebase
                .config()
                .getValue("holiday_promo")
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data, "data");
                });
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(`Error processing config: ${error}`));
```

In my firebase remote config I have a parameter as follows : 
holiday_promo(parameter_key) and value is "promo string" .
But when I console the data, it is empty. 
And get something like this : 
  `{source: "remote"
val: ƒ val()
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: "val" }`
Can someone tell me what is wrong..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must call the function `val()` to get data.

```
firebase
.config()
.getValue("holiday_promo")
.then(data => {
    console.log("data => ", data.val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
firebase
  .config()
  .fetch(0) ...
```

Remote config is cached for 12 hours by default, and enableDeveloperMode doesn't bypass cache, it just allows for more frequent refreshes of it.